# Read values in numeric xml tags using Regex

Tags: regex, xml, regex-negation

I need to read the values of numeric xml tags. e.g.

```
<101>ThisIsOneValue</101>
```

I want one REGex that gives me "ThisIsOneValue"

Answer (score 0):

Very easy: just look for `>` line per line (/`g`) and grab the text that goes after it.

`/\>(.*)/g` should do it.

See https://regex101.com/r/lO1lT5/1 for an example.

If your text would also happen to contain a `>`, then you can test for `<`, digits and then `>`, through e.g. `\<\d+\>(.*)`, see https://regex101.com/r/lO1lT5/2.

Per the new info: https://regex101.com/r/lO1lT5/3 (use `\<\d+\>(\w*)\<\/\d+\>`)

Comment: I am really sorry My tags are <101>HI</101><2>Hello</2>

And i need it to match HI and Hello

Comment: Updated answer. Next time try to be more descriptive in your question.